# Column 'Id' does not belong to table error

Tags: c#, sql

I can populate my grid fine with content from the database whenever I write

```
string qs = "SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetail ";
```

in the code below, but when I use

```
string qs = "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM OrderDetail";
```

it throws an error

> column 'Id' does not belong to table

[image]

My aim is to get the sum of `Amount`, so this is what I have tried.

```
public object Get()
{
    var queryString = Request.Query;
    int skip = Convert.ToInt32(queryString["$skip"]); // get the skip query
    int take = Convert.ToInt32(queryString["$top"]); // get the take query

    string qs = "SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM OrderDetail ";

    if (take != 0)
    {
        qs = qs + " OFFSET " + skip + "ROWS FETCH NEXT " + take + " ROWS ONLY; ";
    }
    else
    {
        qs = qs + "; ";
    }

    string filter = queryString["$filter"];  // get the filter queries

    DataSet data = CreateCommand(qs, cons);
    orderDetails = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new OrderDetail
        {
            Id = r.Field<int>("Id"),
            OrderNo = r.Field<int>("OrderNo"),
            Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
            Amount = r.Field<decimal>("Amount")               

        }).ToList();  // Here, we have converted dataset into list

    IEnumerable<OrderDetail> DataSource = orderDetails;

    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetail", con);

    Int32 count = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();

    con.Close();

    return take != 0 ? Json(new { Items = DataSource, Count = count }) : Json(DataSource);
}
```

Expected out

[image]

Comment: your select didn't include the id field. you have to added to the select list and also add a group by clause.

Comment: It's populating the entire record from the database. This statement 'SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM OrderDetails' is expected to return a single record with sum of all amounts

Comment: But you are asking for id

Comment: Run your query in sql server management studio and ask yourself "what is the ID of this row". Once you build a query where you an answer that question, you will understand why your code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The query

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM OrderDetail
```

you are trying to send will generate a result, that has only one row, one column and that column has the name `Amount`. But later in your code you have the following code:

```
.Select(r => new OrderDetail
{
    Id = r.Field<int>("Id"),
    OrderNo = r.Field<int>("OrderNo"),
    Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
    Amount = r.Field<decimal>("Amount")               

})
```

This tries to read the columns `Id`, `OrderNo`,`Name` and `Amount` from the result set, but the first three columns you try to read don't exists (in the result set). That's why you get the error message "Column 'Id' does not belong to table".

Since you send a `SELECT` query which only returns a 1x1 result set with the column name `Amount`, you can only read the value from that column with `r.Field<decimal>("Amount")`. Remove the construction of the `new OrderDetail` object, since you don't get such a row anyway, and only use `r.Field<decimal>("Amount")` to read the "Amount" value.

Answer (score -2):

```
public object Get()
{
    var queryString = Request.Query;
    int skip = Convert.ToInt32(queryString["$skip"]); // get the skip query
    int take = Convert.ToInt32(queryString["$top"]); // get the take query
    string qs = "Select Id , OrderNo, Name,   Sum(Amount) as Amount from OrderDetail GROUP BY Id , OrderNo, Name ORDER BY Sum(Amount) DESC ";
    if (take != 0)
    {
        qs = qs + " OFFSET " + skip + "ROWS FETCH NEXT " + take + " ROWS ONLY; ";
    }
    else
    {
        qs = qs + "; ";
    }
    string filter = queryString["$filter"];  // get the filter queries
    DataSet data = CreateCommand(qs, cons);
    orderDetails = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new OrderDetail
    {
        Id = r.Field<int>("Id"),
        OrderNo = r.Field<int>("OrderNo"),
        Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
        Amount = r.Field<decimal>("Amount")               

    }).ToList();  // Here, we have converted dataset into list

    IEnumerable<OrderDetail> DataSource = orderDetails;

    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        con.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetail", con);
    Int32 count = (Int32)comm.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    return take != 0 ? Json(new { Items = DataSource, Count = count }) : Json(DataSource);
}
```

Comment: I did tried your way but it's returning all values. I have also tried it in the sql server database and got the desired result. I have updated my question.

Comment: Yikes... don't recommend people use techniques that are vulnerable to sql injection.